# SQL Lead/Lag Smart Solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, lag, lead

I am working for a company that still uses MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and so I cant use Lead/Lag Functions.

I know the general workaround of sub queries with partitions etc to replicate what this does but i am working on a project that requires lots and lots of leads and lags to be used.

Therefore my question is has anybody come up with a smart way of replicating what a lead function does that could be called from a UDF etc that would make this process easier?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, tprev.*
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.? = t.? and   -- partitioning columns
            tprev.? < t.?       -- order by columns
      order by ? desc           -- order by columns, ordering reversed
     ) tprev;
```

This will substitute for a lag of 1 (similar code handles `lead()`).  It can handle multiple columns at the same time.  This covers many common uses of `lag()`.